# Several QR Codes with ARKit

Tags: ios, qr-code, augmented-reality, arkit

In a new project we plan to create following AR showcase:

We want to have a wall with some pipes and cables on it. These will have sensors mounted to control and monitor the pipe/cable-system. Since each sensor will have the same dimensions and appearance we plan to add individual QR Codes to each sensor. Reading the documentation of [ARWorldTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration) and [ARImageTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arimagetrackingconfiguration) shows that ARKit is capable of recognizing known images. But the requirements to images make me wonder if the application would work as we want it to when using several QR Codes:

From [detectionImages](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/2941063-detectionimages):

> [...], identifying art in a museum or adding animated elements to a movie poster.

From Apples Keynote:

> Good Images to Track: High Texture, High local Contrast, well distributed histogram, no repetitive structures

Since QR Codes don't match the requirements completely I'm wondering if it's possible to use about 10 QR Codes and have ARKit recognize each of them individually and reliable. Especially when e.g. 3 Codes are in the view. Does anyone have experience in tracking several QR Codes or even a similar showcase?

Answer (score 1):

Recognizing (several) QR-codes has nothing to do with ARKit and can be done in 3 different ways (AVFramework, `CIDetector`, Vision), of which the latter is preferable in my opinion because you may also want to use its object tracking capabilities (VNTrackObjectRequest). Also it is more robust in my experience.

If you need to place objects in ARKit scene using locations of the QR-codes, you will need to execute `hitTest` on ARFrame to find code's 3D location (transform) in the world. On that location you will need to place a custom ARAnchor. Using the anchor, you can add a custom SceneKit node to the scene.

**UPDATE**: So the suggested strategy would be: 1. find QR codes and their 2D location with Vision, 2. find their 3D location (`worldTransform`) with `ARFrame.hitTest()`, 3. create custom (subclassed) `ARAnchor` and add it to the session, 4. in `renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor)` add a custom node (such as `SCNText` with *billboard constraint*) for your custom `ARAnchor`.

If by any chance you are using RxSwift, it can done the easiest with RxVision framework, because it allows to easily pass the relevant ARFrame along into the handler -

```swift
var requests = [RxVNRequest<ARFrame>]()
let barcodesRequest: RxVNDetectBarcodesRequest<ARFrame> = VNDetectBarcodesRequest.rx.request(symbologies: [.QR])

self
    .barcodesRequest
    .observable
    .observeOn(Scheduler.main)
    .subscribe { [unowned self] (event) in
        switch event {
        case .next(let completion):
            self.detectCodeHandler(value: completion.value, request: completion.request, error: completion.error) // define the method first
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! The second part sounds more like what I want to achieve. My idea basically was that a QR Code is nothing different than a black and white image. Therefore I hoped to use the image recognition capability of ARKit to determine which QR Code is in the View and show individual information (maybe some text etc.) at the corresponding QR Code's location.

If I try to achieve this with ARKit I have to place the ARAnchors by myself with the help of ARFrame and hitTest if I understand you correct? Afterwards I can place the individual information to each of the anchors?

Comment: I did similar things in the past, so feel free to ask for specific code samples. "image recognition capability of ARKit" is definitely NOT helpful for this task.

Comment: thanks so much! So you would recommend to combine ARKit with the Vision Framework for this Use Case? Reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/using_vision_in_real_time_with_arkit) sounds like it really makes sense. Sorry if I'm asking the real stupid questions, I'm not experienced in this topic (hopefully not yet).

Comment: Yes, your recap is correct. 1. find QR codes and their 2D location with Vision, 2. find their 3D location (worldTransform) with ARFrame.hitTest(), 3. create custom (subclassed) ARAnchor and add it to the session, 4. in `renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor)` add a  custom node (such as SCNText with billboard constraint) for your custom ARAnchor.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I guess that's the way we have to go. We are still in the conceptional phase and start implementing in the near future I think. I'll try to give my feedback then!

Answer (score 1):

```
if let image = anchor as? ARImageAnchor{
    guard let buffer: CVPixelBuffer = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage else {
                    print("could not get a pixel buffer")
                    return
    }
    let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: buffer)

    var message = ""
    let features = detector.features(in: image)
    for feature in features as! [CIQRCodeFeature] {
        message = feature.messageString
        break
    }

    if image.referenceImage.name == "QR1"{
        if message == "QR1"{
            // add node 1
        }else{
            sceneView.session.remove(anchor: anchor)
        }
    } else if image.referenceImage.name == "QR2"{
        if message == "QR2"{
            // add node 2
        }else{
            sceneView.session.remove(anchor: anchor)
        }
    }
}
```

`detector` here is `CIDetector`.
Also you need to check  `renderer(_:didUpdate:for:)`. 
I worked on 4 QR codes.
It works assuming no two QR codes can be seen in a frame at same time.